# Selenium find element and click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've this html markup , my target is find th element class an then click on it using selenium

```
<div class="float_left buttons">
  <a href="#" class="button button-3 j-save float_left j-retailer-start-order-submit">Export</a>    
</div>
```

I've tried :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "a[class='button button-3 j-save float_left j-retailer-start-order-submit']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='.button.button-3.j-save.float_left.j-retailer-start-order-submit']"))).click()
```

what is wrong?, tnx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either of the below two lines of code instead:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button button-3 j-save float_left j-retailer-start-order-submit']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Export']"))).click()
```

**Issues in your code:**

In the below code, while using `By.CLASS_NAME` locator strategy, there should not be space between class names

```
By.CLASS_NAME, "a[class='button button-3 j-save float_left j-retailer-start-order-submit']"
```

In the below code, The CSS selector should not contain dots (`.`) before each class name within the square brackets. Also, the class attribute should only contain the space-separated class names without any dots.

```
By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='.button.button-3.j-save.float_left.j-retailer-start-order-submit']"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will click on that link:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.j-save")
))
```

Or if more than one element has the `j-save` class, use this:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.j-retailer-start-order-submit")
))
```

You can also use `By.LINK_TEXT` with `"Export"` (for `a` tag elements only), assuming that's the only `Export` button on the page.